# What's wrong with this CSS / Horizontal responsive menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I need some help with this responsive navigation.

What I want is a horizontal menu including some padding and centered position. But all I've got is a vertical menu.

When the menu shows up on mobile / smaller screen-devices it show's up as I want. But not on desktop.

```
/*DESKTOP - Version (inside media-query)*/
ul.menu{
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.menu li{
    display: inline;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #80b4e0;
}
ul.menu li a:first-child{
    padding-top: 20px;
}ul.menu li a:last-child{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.menu li:hover{
    background: #80b4e0;
    color: #FFF;
}
ul.menu li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #80b4e0;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
ul.menu a:hover{
    color: #FFF;
}

/*Mobile version - mobile first*/
ul.menu{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.menu li{
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #80b4e0;
}
ul.menu li a:first-child{
    padding-top: 20px;
}ul.menu li a:last-child{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.menu li:hover{
    background: #80b4e0;
    color: #FFF;
}
ul.menu li a{
    display: block;
    color: #80b4e0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
ul.menu a:hover{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

START
    OM HUNDSALONGEN
    BOKA TID
    AKTUELLT
    KONTAKTA OSS

Comment: Can we have your code in fiddle.

Comment: What is your HTML, and if posible please insert fiddle demo

Comment: HTML implemented. But i can't get fiddle to work. Give it a check at https://jsfiddle.net/ft18c24u/1/

Answer (score 0):

This fixes most of it

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 770px)
    ul.menu {
        text-align: center;
    }
    ul.menu li {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 22px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #80b4e0;
    }
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 770px) {
  ul.menu {
    text-align: center;
  }
  ul.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #80b4e0;
  }
  ul.menu li a:first-child {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  ul.menu li a:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  ul.menu li:hover {
    background: #80b4e0;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  ul.menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: #80b4e0;
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  ul.menu a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
  }
}
/*Mobile version - mobile first*/

ul.menu {
  background: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.menu li {
  font-size: 22px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #80b4e0;
}
ul.menu li a:first-child {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
ul.menu li a:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.menu li:hover {
  background: #80b4e0;
  color: #FFF;
}
ul.menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #80b4e0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
ul.menu a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-start" class="menu">
  <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-21"><a href="http://oneconsultant.se/ninas/">START</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-20"><a href="http://oneconsultant.se/ninas/om-hundsalongen/">OM HUNDSALONGEN</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://oneconsultant.se/ninas/boka-tid/">BOKA TID</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="http://oneconsultant.se/ninas/aktuellt/">AKTUELLT</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-19"><a href="http://oneconsultant.se/ninas/kontakta-oss/">KONTAKTA OSS</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ft18c24u/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Change Your CSS Code

```
/*Mobile version - mobile first*/
ul.menu{

    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: center;

}
ul.menu li{
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #80b4e0;
    display:inline-block;
}
ul.menu li a:first-child{
    padding-top: 20px;
}ul.menu li a:last-child{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.menu li:hover{
    background: #80b4e0;
    color: #FFF;
}
ul.menu li a{
    display: block;
    color: #80b4e0;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul.menu a:hover{
    color: #FFF;
}
@media  (max-width: 768px){    
ul.menu{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
ul.menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #80b4e0;
}
ul.menu li a:first-child{
    padding-top: 20px;
}ul.menu li a:last-child{
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.menu li:hover{
    background: #80b4e0;
    color: #FFF;
}
ul.menu li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #80b4e0;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
ul.menu a:hover{
    color: #FFF;
}

}
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/ft18c24u/5/